# Is the phrase "using doping" correct?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

**Using doping** in the following context sounds peculiar to me:

> Researchers have said that 30 cases of Meldonium use were opened in
>   2018, while only 10 cases were opened in 2019. She has added that it
>   is neglectful, stupid and irresponsible to use Meldonium nowadays.
>   Sports lawyers believe that using Meldonium is not the same as **using
>   doping**, however, they are wrong, according to Pakhnotskaya.

Is **using doping** correct here?

Answer (score 2):

That sentence is grammatically correct, as **doping** is used as a *verbal noun/gerund*.

You probably have seen many examples of these without realising:

> I like **running** to keep fit.
>
> My **hearing** isn't as good as it used to be.
>
> **Driving** can be stressful.

That being said, the sentence does *sound* a bit odd. Personally I would shorten it to just:

> Using Meldonium is not the same as doping.

Comment: My original question was edited by RubioRic and is no longer the question I asked.

Comment: The query is about "using doping"  I don't think "using doping" is correct.  I know "doping" is OK, but that wasn't the question.  Is "using doping" correct?

Comment: @Hiphouse The edit to your question doesn't change my answer.

Comment: Thanks Dan, so grammatically correct, but just sounds odd :)  Ah, the joys of English grammar!